# Puzzle -- exposing a public sub-member of private member with custom type

Tags: scala, scope, access-modifiers

I would like to do something like this (example is simplified, but contains all the crucial pieces):

```
class Master
{
  type DataType = Int
  var counter : DataType = 0
}

class Slave(private val master : Master)
{
  val counter = master.counter  // (*)
}
```

And here (*) I get error:

> private value master escapes its defining scope as part of type
>   Slave.this.master.DataType
>
> val counter = master.counter

I understand the error, but I don't understand the reason - the type is part of the class `Master`, not the object `master`, so it is important if the class is private, not an object. Well, at least in theory.

It is easy to make a quick workaround:

```
  val counter : Master#DataType = master.counter
```

But I believe this is an explicit version of the exactly same code as before, it "only" takes more typing. Is this a feature then?

**QUESTION:**

Can a type (here DataType) be dependent of the object, and not the class (i.e. type definition per instance of the class) in Scala?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are wrong when you think

> this is an explicit version of the exactly same code as before

`Master#DataType` and `master.DataType` are two *different* types.

`master.DataType` is the type of those `DataType` instances which have `master` as outer object. In other words, precisely what you ask, but obviously then `master` *is* part of the type, and the type can't be exposed if `master` isn't.

`Master#DataType` is the type of any `DataType` instance for any outer object (equivalent to `Master.DataType` in Java).

REPLY TO THE COMMENT:

Type members can be overridden in a subclass (including an anonymous subclass containing only one object), but only by a compatible type. And in your example `DataType` is already concrete in `Master`, so the only compatible class with it is itself. So something like

```
val a = new Master {
  override type DataType = String
}
```

won't typecheck, which makes sense: you'd get `var counter: String = 0`, which is nonsense. But

```
val a = new Master {
  override type DataType = Int
}
```

will work (but isn't too useful).

So it only ever makes sense to override *abstract* type members. But they are type-checked in the same way as inner classes, so `a.DataType` is not generally considered the same as `b.DataType` -- even if they can't actually be different!

Comment: Thank you, so if I understand this correctly (however I didn't read it in "Programming in Scala" I believe -- or maybe it slipped), you can define type per instance of the class, not only per class.

Comment: Thank you for the update, this is very valuable, unfortunately I cannot upvote your post more than 1 :-)

Comment: This is one of those useful things in Scala that can be a "gotcha" when coming from other OOP languages. Very succinct answer; worth my upvote ;).